# Unread messages count on XMPP

Tags: xmpp, mongoose-im

I am using MongooseIM to develop a XMPP-based Chat App and I'm trying to implement the number of unread messages in my app.

I'm using [XEP-0022 (Message Events)](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html) to track when a message is received from the server, received from the client, seen from the other client and [XEP-0430 (Inbox)](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0430.html) to keep track of unread messages that are read as soon as I retrieve them from MAM.

My main issue here is that, when requesting messages from Inbox, it returns ***all of the messages*** and not only the text ones. To clarify: it returns also messages that are sent to ack that a message is received and all of the in-between messages, thus incrementing the unread counter and making it very unrealistic.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XEP-0333: Chat Markers](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html) instead of XEP-0022 (marked as obsolete) to pass delivery/read status around. MongooseIM Inbox is aware of XEP-0333 markers and will not count them towards the total number of unread messages. This is the easiest option if you have control over the XMPP extensions in use.

Comment: Thank you, it works. One last thing: how can I know that the server accepted the message without 0022, now?

Comment: Actually managed to achieve it using XEP-0184. Thanks again a lot!